# How can a newbie fan read the Marvel storylines/events without confusion?

Tags: marvel

I am new to marvel and i'm reading some old stuff out of the essentials which is pretty simple stuff. I'm just not sure what to do when it comes to crossovers and important events because i read up on comics that tie in with many events in the MU and it looks like a lot.

I think its all a bit confusing and i don't even know what order the Marvel events like Civil War go in and i dont know if a newer fan can read them without confusion but i want to try.

Can someone put all the marvel events in order for me and include the year it came out and all the tie ins? Thanks :))

Comment: This question is a bit too broad currently.  I'd recommend narrowing it down to just a list of the order the crossovers happened in.  Then ask separate questions looking for reading orders of each crossover's tie ins.

Comment: I don't think it's feasible to answer this. Based on my reading assorted Marvel info on Wikis, the answer would contain **enormous** amount of information in a very complex graph.

Comment: “Can someone put all the Marvel events in order for me and include the year it came out and all the tie ins?” Not with today’s computing power, no.

Answer (score 16):

#### Tayler, what you are asking for is next to impossible. Comics may be one of the most confusing and contradictory things since physicists started asking about the Big Bang.

I say this as a reader of comics for over forty years. I have read the big two, DC and Marvel and two dozen smaller/independent comic companies.

- As a new comic reader, my advice is to find the heroes you like and follow them. These will be the stories that resonate with you and you will have the greatest interest in. All heroes are not created equally. What you like about one group will be completely absent in the next.

**For example: X-men vs the Avengers**

- The X-men deal with the evolutionary offshoot of humanity, commonly called mutants and their struggles for human acceptance, dealing with members of their community who seek to control or even dominate the human race. Their stories tend to revolve around how they will protect themselves from humans or other mutant threats.
- The Avengers, on the other hand, are most often superheroes who work with or sometimes for the government preventing threats of an extraterrestrial or extra-dimensional nature. They are heroes of a variety of origins and power levels. Their stories vary from large-scale multi-hero adventures to very personal struggles dealing with their lifestyle.

**Over time, as your familiarity with the heroes grows:**

- You will eventually want to discover more about them and their relationships to other heroes. Since you will probably not be in a position to buy every appearance a particular hero shows up in, you might want to use online resources to increase your knowledge.
- Use wikis as a way of figuring out how characters related and in what story arcs. Most wikis like the Marvel Wiki and Wikipedia will list famous story arcs and the heroes/villains involved in that arc.

**This is not something someone can do for you.** This is an exploration of an industry that is nearly a hundred years old with thousands of characters and hundreds of thousands of stories, both individual and collectively.

- Strangely enough, even the enthusiasts can't keep it all straight so part of the fun will be in the slow exploration of a character to discover how they may have changed over the decades, or across various media.
- A comic hero which migrates to television or to the movies may only bear a passing resemblance, in some cases they only keep their name but how they act, appear, or are written can be completely different.
- Some transformations are so complete, different directors will refuse to even acknowledge the previous movies. (This happens in comics too, if a writer has had a long run on a comic, the next writer may throw out the parts of the previous writers work he did not like.)

The Scifi-Stackexchange is a great place to ask questions about a particular hero or a story arc you didn't quite understand. Here are a few examples to help you create better questions in the future. Good luck and welcome aboard.

[Is the Hulk Immortal?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/is-the-hulk-immortal)

[As of 2012, how many different canon versions of the Superman character exist?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22733/as-of-2012-how-many-different-canon-versions-of-the-superman-character-exist)

[Why can't the Phoenix Five destroy the Red Hulk?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21886/why-cant-the-phoenix-five-destroy-the-red-hulk)

[What was the implication at the end of The Dark Knight Rises?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/what-was-the-implication-at-the-end-of-the-dark-knight-rises)

[Who are all these Avengers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15751/who-are-all-these-avengers)

Comment: Thanks! This honestly eased me a little because i usually get so worried about continuity. I already started my exploration of my comics on interested in- starting with hulk. He is pretty neat! :)

Comment: "Comics may be one of the most confusing and contradictory things since physicists started asking about the Big Bang." xD